# including "-" in $.extend from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create simple Jquery plugin.
The problem is when I change the name of settings's properties from backgroundcolor1 to background-color1 or just include "-" in the property name, the compiler does not allow me to do it.

Why is that?

```js
  (function ( $ ) {
 
    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {
 
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            color: "#556b2f",
            backgroundcolor1: "white"
        }, options );
 
        // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
        return this.css({
            "color": settings.color,
            "background-color": settings.backgroundcolor1
        });
 
    };
 
}( jQuery ));

  $(document).ready(function () {
    
        $("h2").greenify({ color:"red",backgroundcolor1:"yellow"});

    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2> for test</h2>
```

I have added the code, you can try using background-color1 in place of backgroundcolor1, and you will see that compiler not allowing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use quoted object keys:

```
$.fn.greenify = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        "color": "#556b2f",
        "background-color": "white"
    }, options);

    return this.css({
        "color": settings["color"],
        "background-color": settings["background-color"]
    });
}

$("h2").greenify({ "color": "red", "background-color": "yellow" });
```

Answer (score 1):

The "-" sign is used as the minus operator in JavaScript and will thus try to calculate the variables instead. It can not be used in variable naming.